# Splice Array in Postgres

Tags: arrays, postgresql

Is it possible to (easily) splice arrays in Postgres? For example, I want to replace all values of `4` with the values `8` and `12`, so an array of `{2, 4, 7}` should become `{2, 8, 12, 7}`. Perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way, but I need to maintain the integer array column type for these columns. Thanks for any guidance you can give me.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by easily, however Postgresql's manual presents the way of slicing an array. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/arrays.html

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `UNNEST`?

```
WITH rep(ord, what, with_what) AS(
  VALUES (1,4,8),
  (2,4,12)
)
SELECT array_agg(COALESCE(with_what,elem) ORDER BY no, ord) AS new_array
FROM(
  SELECT * 
  FROM UNNEST('{2, 4, 7}'::INTEGER[]) WITH ORDINALITY AS arr(elem, no)    
    LEFT JOIN rep ON arr.elem = rep.what
) AS q;
```

This way you can define a whole set of replaces easily.